# SQL- parent team name display depends on child team atleast one employee

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have 3 tables

teams

```
   id  name
   6   WD
   7   LGO
   10  PS
   11  EM
   12  SO
   13  DM
   14  DMS
   15  CRO
   16  T / T
```

team_mapping

```
   id      team_id      parent_team_id
   1       6            0
   2       7            0
   3       10           7
   4       11           7
   5       12           0
   6       13           12
   7       14           12
   8       15           0
   9       16           15
```

employees

```
   id      name       team_id
    3       Bk        6
    4       Nr        6
    5       SV        7
    6       GK        10
    7       JPD       13
    8       BSY       16
    9       MK        16
    10      Ps        16
    11      Bji       16
```

my query is

```
SELECT t.*
FROM teams t
INNER JOIN employees e ON t.id = e.team_id
INNER JOIN team_mapping tm ON t.id = tm.team_id
WHERE tm.parent_team_id = '0'
GROUP BY t.id
```

it display like

```
    id         name
    6           WD
    7           LGO
```

but i want to display parent team name only if atleast have one employee in the either parent team or child team. ie output like

```
   team_id    name
    6          WD
    7          LGO
    12         SO
    15         CRO
```

Please help me to write a query and output should be display as above result

Thanks

Comment: How can id 15 come in the output when it is not there in either of Team Mapping or employees table

Comment: id i5 updated. Please check thanks

Comment: what is the foreign key mapping between three tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select distinct id, name
from teams t inner join
    (SELECT case when tm.parent_team_id = 0 then tm.team_id else tm.parent_team_id end as TID
    FROM teams t
    INNER JOIN team_mapping tm ON t.id = tm.team_id
    INNER JOIN  employees e ON tm.team_id = e.team_id  ) as table2
on t.id = table2.TID
```

This code is in SQL Server

Here sub query returns duplicate values, and we can't use distinct with the case statement. To avoid duplicate values and to get the parent team name inner join with sub query is needed

Comment: Thanks you very much, it works what we expect result

Answer (score 0):

here is what your query should look like

```
SELECT DISTINCT CAST(t.id AS INT) id,t.name
FROM teams t
LEFT JOIN employees e ON t.id = e.team_id
LEFT JOIN team_mapping tm ON t.id = tm.team_id
WHERE tm.parent_team_id = '0'
```

You can use LEFT JOIN for your query.

Then I removed the GROUP BY clause and replace it with DISTICNT.

I just use CAST(t.id AS INT) id so the result will be arranged, either way you can just remove the cast part, the only difference is the arrangement of the result.

Comment: Thanks, it display all team if employee not in team